# Custom Comparison to create new Pandas dataframe after Comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new Pandas dataframe based on a comparison with 2 dataframes.

I've looked for similares answers here, but I haven't managed to get the result I want.

I have this 2 dataframes:

```
totalDistrict = dataFrameDemography[['district_name', 'population_density']]
districtsWithRecyclingAreas = dataFrameRecyclingAreas['DISTRICT']
```

I extract the columns I wanted from 2 different CSV files using Pandas. The tables look as follows:

```
             district_name  population_density
0                    Centro           25340.69
1                Arganzuela           23306.44
2                    Retiro           21867.53
3                 Salamanca           26830.78
4                 Chamartín           15723.25
5                    Tetuan           28664.25
6                  Chamberí           29049.26
7       Fuencarral-El Pardo            1003.00
8           Moncloa-Aravaca            2515.26
9                    Latina            9183.75
10              Carabanchel           17316.88
11                    Usera           17535.32
12       Puente de Vallecas           15345.01
13                Moratalaz           15493.59
14            Ciudad Lineal           18455.56
15                Hortaleza            6973.33
16               Villaverde            7059.13
17        Villa de Vallecas            2026.82
18                Vicálvaro            1981.11
19      San Blas-Canillejas            6934.37
20                  Barajas            1076.06
```

```
0              ARGANZUELA
1                 BARAJAS
2             CARABANCHEL
3               CHAMARTIN
4           CIUDAD LINEAL
5     FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO
6               HORTALEZA
7                  LATINA
8         MONCLOA-ARAVACA
9               MORATALAZ
10     PUENTE DE VALLECAS
11    SAN BLAS-CANILLEJAS
12                  USERA
13              VICALVARO
14      VILLA DE VALLECAS
15             VILLAVERDE
Name: DISTRICT, dtype: object
```

Now, what I want to do is to generate a Dataframe with all the districts and their population density, with an extra column indicating if they have a recycling area or not (1 or 0 value f.e).

I just don't know how to do that because columns names are different in each dataframe, and also the districts are written in capitals in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `.str.upper` to convert the `district_name` column to upper case then use `Series.isin` to find the elements in `district_name` which are also present in the  series `districtsWithRecyclingAreas`:

```
totalDistrict['recycling'] = totalDistrict['district_name'].str.upper()\
                            .isin(districtsWithRecyclingAreas).view('i1')
```

---

```
          district_name  population_density  recycling
0                Centro            25340.69          0
1            Arganzuela            23306.44          1
2                Retiro            21867.53          0
3             Salamanca            26830.78          0
4             Chamartín            15723.25          0
5                Tetuan            28664.25          0
6              Chamberí            29049.26          0
7   Fuencarral-El Pardo             1003.00          1
8       Moncloa-Aravaca             2515.26          1
9                Latina             9183.75          1
10          Carabanchel            17316.88          1
11                Usera            17535.32          1
12   Puente de Vallecas            15345.01          1
13            Moratalaz            15493.59          1
14        Ciudad Lineal            18455.56          1
15            Hortaleza             6973.33          1
16           Villaverde             7059.13          1
17    Villa de Vallecas             2026.82          1
18            Vicálvaro             1981.11          0
19  San Blas-Canillejas             6934.37          1
20              Barajas             1076.06          1
```

Comment: @JavierAlonsoDelgado Noting to worry..you can safely ignore that warning..probably you are using old pandas version.

Comment: When I print the result, all entries have 0 recycling areas

Comment: Does the answer working properly on the sample data you have provided?

Comment: I'm using the provied data in the main post, but not getting the results you provided in your answer

Comment: For me its working properly on the sample data..BTW what is your pandas version?

Comment: I'm using Google Colaboratory, I just impor pandas in the script. I'm getting 2 dataframes from CSV, then creating the 2 reduced dataframes as shown in the main post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224927/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-javier-alonso-delgado).